# Weird Error Occurred During Function Run

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, console

I have the following function :

```
var appendStructure = {

        init : function(wrapper,structure,cls,callback) {

            $(wrapper).appendTo(container).hide()
            var object = $(container).find(cls);
            $(structure.join('')).appendTo(object);
            showObj(object,function() {
                if(opts.centerObj == true) {
                    $(window).resize(function() {
                        var cssProps = getProps(object);
                        object.css(cssProps);
                    });
                }
                if(typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback();
                }
            });

        }
}
```

And the other functions that are called within it:

```
var getProps = function(obj) {
    return {
        'position' :'absolute',
        'top' : (($(window).height() - $(obj).outerHeight()) / 2)+'px',
        'left' : (($(window).width() - $(obj).outerWidth()) / 2)+'px'
    }
}

var showObj = function(obj,callback) {
    return setTimeout(function () {
        if(opts.centerObj == true) {
            var cssProps = getProps(obj);
            obj.css(cssProps).fadeIn('slow');
        }
            else {
                obj.fadeIn('slow');
            }
        if(typeof callback == 'function') {
            callback();
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

And I run the function like this:

```
if(appendStructure.init(wrapper.login,structure.login,'.content-login')){
        console.log('Object Appended'); 
    }
        else {
            console.log('Error');   
        }
```

My question is, why is the console outputting `Error`, because the function actually works and everything that is suppose to happen, happens ?

Comment: I'm thinking that if the function works and everything else fires correctly, then the problem must lie somewhere in the if statement. What do you get if you change that line to `console.log(appendStructure.init(wrapper.login, structure.login, '.content-login'));` ? I'd be interested to know what the if is attempting to evaluate against.

Comment: @Mark Tabler, it returns `undefined` if I change the `console.log('Error')` to `console.log(appendStructure.init(wrapper.login, structure.login, '.content-login'));` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`appendStructure.init` does not `return` any value, hence the return value will be `undefined`. `undefined` evaluates to `false`, so the `else` branch of your `if...else` statement is executed.

Comment: indeed, it returns undefined in the console, so it means that that's nothing wrong with that function ? I was doing that if because I wanted to see if something happens if I run the function, I had some problems when trying to compile it and I thought that checking with `if()` would get me at least a clue. Is there another way to check if a functions actually runs ?

Comment: You could use `try...catch` to find you whether a function throws an error and then act accordingly.

Comment: Oh, like I would do with PHP. Thanks :)